# verification: did I proof continuity right?

Tags: general-topology, proof-verification, continuity

Let $\mathbb{R}$ be endowed with the lower limit topology $\mathcal{T}_l$. That is, the smallest topology on $\mathbb{R}$ which contains all the intervals of type $[a,b)$ with $a,b\in \mathbb{R}$. Is $f:\mathbb{R}\rightarrow\mathbb{R}, f(x)=-x$ continuous?

I thought not, but I don't know if my proof is right. My proof was the following:

Let $U\in\mathcal{T}_l$ and $a,b\in U, a<b$. Then $f^{-1}([a,b))= [-a,-b)=(-b,-a]\not\in \mathcal{T}_l$, so by the definition of continuity $\exists U\in\mathcal{T}_l$ such that $f^{-1}(U)\not\in\mathcal{T}_l$, thus $f$ is not continuous.

Is this a correct proof? Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have the essential idea, but you’ve stated it rather badly. To show that $f$ is not continuous, you need only find an open set $U$ such that $f^{-1}[U]$ is not open. You are correct in thinking that taking $U=[a,b)$ will work, but you need to say that that’s what you’re doing:

> Let $U=[a,b)$, where $a,b\in\Bbb R$ with $a<b$; by definition $U\in\mathcal{T}_\ell$.

That is, you want $U$ to be specifically $[a,b)$: you don’t want $[a,b)$ just to be some open subset of $U$, which is what you’ve actually said.

> Then $f^{-1}[U]=\{-x:a\le x<b\}=\{x:a\le -x<b\}=\{x:-a\ge x>-b\}=(-b,-a]$.

Note that it is *not* true that this is $[-a,-b)$: by definition $[-a,-b)=\{x\in\Bbb R:-a\le x<b\}=\varnothing$, since $-a>-b$.

Now you have to show that $(-b,-a]\notin\mathcal{T}_\ell$, and you haven’t actually done this. The fact that $(-b,-a]$ is not of the form $[c,d)$ is *not* enough to ensure that it’s not in $\mathcal{T}_\ell$: the intervals of the form $[c,d)$ are only a *base* for the topology $\mathcal{T}_\ell$, which contains many sets not of this form. For instance, every subset of $\Bbb R$ that is open in the usual Euclidean topology is also open in the lower limit topology; if you’ve not already done so, you should try to prove this. This means, for instance, that the set $(-b,-a)$ *is* in $\mathcal{T}_\ell$.

As it happens, $(-b,-a]$ is not in $\mathcal{T}_\ell$, but you have to do a little work to show this. Since $(-b,-a)$ is in $\mathcal{T}_\ell$, the point $-a$ must be the one that’s causing trouble. Does $(-b,-a]$ contain any basic open nbhd of $-a$? No: such a nbhd would have the form $[-a,-a+\epsilon)$ for some $\epsilon>0$, and then the point $-a+\frac{\epsilon}2$ would be in $[-a,-a+\epsilon)\setminus(-b,-a]$, showing that $[-a,-a+\epsilon)\nsubseteq(-b,-a]$. Thus, $-a$ has no open nbhd contained in $(-b,-a]$, and therefore $(-b,-a]$ cannot be open in the lower limit topology.

Comment: thank you very much! this is helping a lot :)

Comment: @JBIBB: You’re very welcome!

Answer (score 0):

First off, $[-a,-b) = \{x \mid -a \leq x < -b\}$ and $(-b,-a] = \{x \mid -b < x \leq -a]$ are different things.

You also want to assume $a < b$ to ensure $[a,b)$ is non-empty, for otherwise your counterexample does not work.

You claim that $(-b,-a] \notin \mathcal{T}_l$, which you have to justify. It is important to notice that $\mathcal{T}_l$ is **generated** by intervalls of the form $[a,b)$, but contains even more sets. For example $(0,1) = \bigcup_{n \geq 1} [1/n,1) \in \mathcal{T}_l$.

So for your counterexample to work you have to show $\mathcal{T}_l$ does not contain $(-b,-a]$. This can be done by explicitely calculating $\mathcal{T}_l$ and showing that $(-b,-a] \in \mathcal{T}_l$ if $a < b$. (**Hint**: Using the above example you can see that $\mathcal{T}_l$ must contain the half-open intervalls $[a,b)$ (with $b = \infty$ allowed) and open intervalls $(a,b)$ (with $a = -\infty$ and $b = \infty$) allowed. Check if this already is a topology, or what is missing.)